# Horizontal scroll for HorizontalStackLayout in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I'm trying to display a bunch of thumbnail images in a `HorizontalStackLayout` in a .NET MAUI app. How do I make the `HorizontalStackLayout` horizontally scrollable?

Images line up nicely in my `HorizontalStackLayout` but I can't see all the images because the `HorizontalStackLayout` is not scrolling horizontally.

How do I allow "overflow" in this situation so that the user can scroll horizontally to see the remaining images that didn't fit the width of the screen?

I'd rather not use the `CarouselView` in this scenario because I'd like a as many images to be visible as possible without any user interaction.

Comment: Use a ScrollView

Comment: Tried that but it didn’t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to achieve your need:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Sample}"
                        ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Source_}"
                           Margin="100"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```